# Styling Tkinter UI?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Is there an easy way to style UI written in python using `Tkinter`? I need to turn something very basic like this: 
[image]

Into something styled and more fancy looking like this:
[image]

Is there a drag, drop and resize tool that can help me build the UI quickly and efficiently?

Comment: Did you consider anything more suitable for styled UI than TkInter ? Sciter for example. It has  Python bindings : https://github.com/sciter-sdk/pysciter In this case you can use well known HTML/CSS constructs for such UIs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ttk` widgets. Those are themed.

You can find example of tile (bitmap) based themes [here](http://tktable.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tktable/tile-themes/).

Not being a `tcl` expert, I'm not sure you to get `tcl/tk` to recognize and load these themes. But [here](https://code.activestate.com/lists/python-tkinter-discuss/3706/) are some pointers.